# Несложные Статьи и Книги на Английском

Tags: c++, книги, visual-c++

Подошел к своей подруге-лингвисту с вопросом:"Хочу выучить Английский, преимущественно технический. Если я уеду за границу на пару месяцев, то это мне чем нибудь поможет?"

На это она мне сказала:"Не занимайся фигней! Если тебе нужен технический язык, то садись и читай книжки, первое время будет муторно. но это самый короткий способ к изучению ТЕХНИЧЕСКОГО языка."

Как лингвист она не смогла посоветовать мне конкретное техническое чтиво.

Поэтому я пришел за ответом к вам. Посоветуйте, пожалуйста не сложную для меня(Pre Intermediate) техническую литературу.(желательно по программированию или дискретной математике)

Я-Студент-С++ программист, стаж год. Знание языка Pre Intermediate.

Заранее благодарен за рекомендуемую литературу и любые советы, которые помогут изучить мне язык.

p.s. Прошу прощения за метки не совсем по теме. Нужных мне не было. На мой взгляд это наиболее подходящие-хотел бы литературу именно по этим темам.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и другая литература по С++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если Вы уже читали какую то переведенную книгу по с++, но найдите ее английский оригинал. Вы будете понимать, о чем текст и сможете догадываться о значении слов. И начинайте читать. Читайте до упора. Где то в середине будет хотеться забросить, будет казаться, что оно абсолютно непонятно. Но главное не сдаваться.
Но ещё нужен "слуховой навык". Наиболее просто его получить - это на ютубе выбирать видео (его там хватает) и смотреть, в начале с субтитрами, а потом и так.

А теперь о реальных книгах. Рекомедую почитать [The Design and Evolution of C++](http://www.amazon.com/Design-Evolution-C-Bjarne-Stroustrup/dp/0201543303).

Но не обязательно читать именно техническую литературу. Выбирайте любую книгу, у которой оригинал на английском, а русский перевод Вы знаете достаточно хорошо. Я, к примеру, читал Винни Пуха. Очень занимательно искать различия (к примеру сова в английском варианте на самом то деле мужского рода:) ). Многие рекомендуют читать Гарри Поттера (после просмотра фильмов).

Также хорошо читать не с экрана, а с "Читалки" (Электронной книги, E-Ink). В многие из них встроены словари и перевод можно подсмотреть.

**UPD**

В Википедии есть интересный раздел - [simple english](http://simple.wikipedia.org/), для чтения на котором  нужно всего то 850 слов. А если знать [1500](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/BE_1500) - то будет понятно все.

Если хочется читать хорошие (и самое главное - свежие!) тематические книги на английском, то есть смысл присмотреться к сервису [safari online](https://ssl.safaribooksonline.com/trial?iid=anon-home-redirect) - издательство O'Reilly выкладывает драфты будущих книг. Но он немножко платный - от 10 евро месяц за пять книг в месяц. Но там только по с++ более [сотни книг](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/category/information-technology-and-software-development/programming/cplusplus).

для улучшения понимая речи можно ещё слушать [esl](http://www.eslpod.com/website/index_new.html). очень занимательно. Кстати, там иногда говорят и на околокомпьютерные темы. Например, как покупать новый компьютер - [ESLPodcast 20 - Buying a New Computer](http://www.eslpod.com/website/show_podcast.php?issue_id=1770056).

Answer (score 2):

Могу рассказать про свой опыт. Просто читать одну какую-то книгу на английском не очень эффективно. Гораздо полезнее использовать английские статьи и документацию в повседневной работе. Если возникает какой-то вопрос, старайтесь формулировать свои запросы в Google на английском. Соответственно, читайте английские ответы. Очень часто ответы будут на StackOverflow или [www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/), если мы говорим о C++. Поначалу будет сложновато, но уже через месяц вы будете более-менее свободно понимать техническую литературу.